# create quarterly index in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

hi i am trying to create quarterly index in ES using log-stash , i know how to create index weekly in log-stash 
 here is my piece of configuration -

```
> output {
>       elasticsearch {
>           hosts => "localhost"
>           index => "logstash-%{+xxxx.ww}"
>           
>           
>       }
>       stdout{}
>     }
```

but how can i create quarterly index or  how we can have month in any variable so i can calculate the quarter .
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date math currently doesn't support specifying quarters `Q` and [an issue is still open](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15612) to improve upon this.

Ideally it would be nice if we could circumvent this shortcoming with something like `now-3M/3M` but multiples of rounding are not supported either.

Until the issue is resolved, one solution would be to use monthly indices and when a quarter has gone, reindex the three previous monthly indices into a single quarter index.

Another solution is to compute the quarter beforehand in a Logstash `ruby` filter and then use it in the `elasticsearch` output, like this:

```
filter {
   ruby {
      code => "event.set('quarter', Date.today.year + '-' + (Date.today.month / 3.0).ceil)"
   }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost"
      index => "logstash-%{quarter}"
  }
}
```

Comment: hi i added ruby filter but its index created like this -  logstash-%{quarter}

Comment: Which version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: i m using 6.1.3

Comment: hi was missing the conversion ruby {
            code => "
                event.set('quarter', Date.today.year.to_s + '-' + ((Date.today.month / 3.0).ceil).to_s)
            "
        }   its working now , thanks